# JSON retrieving object via variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've created a .post form that returns a JSON string and I need to get the data based on the name of the select boxes. please refer to the following example.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('/seller/product_upload/helpers/jpost_product_form_autofill.php',{product_id:$("input[name='product_id']").val()},function(data){
        alert(data);
        if(data!='false'){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $("#attributes_table select").each(function(){
                var select=$(this);
                select.find("option").each(function(){
                    var option=$(this);
                    var select_name=select.attr('name');
                    alert(select_name);
                    alert(obj.select_name);
                    if(option.val()==obj.select_name){
                        option.attr('selected','selected');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The main section of concern here is actually the bottom `if` part. `obj.select_name` is not the main object name here. It is actually the name of the `selectbox` which I had made it coincidental to my array key values parsed in JSON.

But now the system keeps alerting undefined for `obj.select_name`. Is there any way in which i can parse select_name as a string first before having it parsed as a JSON object?

Comment: there's no such thing as a "json object". There's json strings, which can be decoded into a native data structure. if you get an undefined error, then log the decoded data structure to the console and see what's really in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to do that :

```
var name = 'select_name';
alert(obj[name]);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks all for the help. The above answer works!. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you need to use square brackets to use an unknown string as an index. That said, you can use jQuery's `val` function to simplify your code. You don't need to manually set the option values, `val` can set them just like it can read them. Lke this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$("#attributes_table select").each(function(){
    var select = $(this);
    select.val(obj[select.attr('name')]);
});
```

You can also do this, since `val` will automatically do `forEach` inside itself.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$("#attributes_table select").val(function(){
    return obj[$(this).attr('name')];
});
```